# SSIS Excel Destination only output numeric columns

Tags: ssis

I have a SQL table I tried to use as input and I used Excel destination for the output.  I tried converting the input columns from string to Unicode; and I mapped the converted Unicode columns to excel destination.

[image: converted column]

When I run the actual table in SSMS there are data in the work_order column, but in the excel output, the work_order column is blank.

this problem exists for all my character columns output.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: You can save yourself some troubleshooting by performing the conversion in your source. Instead of selecting MyTable, write the query that shapes your data for your destination e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(60), T.work_order_) work_order FROM dbo.MyTable AS T;`

Comment: Thank you.  I just tried that.  I removed the data conversion step and added the syntax in the source, it showed 160 rows in the data flow task but when I go to the Excel sheet, all columns are blank, it didn't even output numeric columns.  Not sure why.

Comment: Try removing the excel destination and even the connection manager and then add those back in and see if things magically fix themselves. Excel is not well behaved when it comes to SSIS

Comment: I added a new Excel destination and connection, and now I get several error messages.  I am pasting one of them.  This column has 250 bytes in the table and conversion query.   "[Excel Destination [2]] Error: There was an error with Excel Destination.Inputs[Excel Destination Input].Columns[work_order_] on Excel Destination.Inputs[Excel Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."."